# Excel Formula Won't Show Part Definitions

Tags: excel, formula

Ok, weird question here.  I'm not even sure what to call it because I've never had this problem before.

I'm using Excel 365.  Out of the blue this morning, Excel won't show me the parts of a formula as I'm typing it in the formula bar or in the cell (as shown below).

[Missing Formula Information Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zD1g.png)

For example, when I start typing "=s", a dropdown appears below the formula bar showing me all the equations that start with s.  That's still working fine.  When I type "=sum(" I then expect to see another drop down that defines the parts of the formula, so in this case, I'd expect to see "(number1, [number2], ...)."  I'm not seeing this anymore.  Once I type the "(", there's no more drop downs.  This is true for any formula I type, either in the formula bar or in a cell.  It's no longer showing me the parts of the formula to input.  It'll give me drop downs and information until I get to the "(" and then there's nothing.  Did I hit some obscure key combination by accident to turn this off?  How do I turn it back on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of frustration and delving through the Options, I found the answer.  Don't know how it got unchecked.

Options > Advanced > Display > check "Show Function ScreenTips"